# Не работает pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

я скачал pygame,
но:

```
import pygame
```

выдает:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Ну а каким образом Питон должен найти его в этой папке "своих программ"?? Устанавливайте модули Питона через специальный консольную утилиту для этого – `pip`. Либо копируйте в рабочую директорию, откуда запускаете интерпретатор, но без особой нужды лучше не стоит.

Comment: У вас есть в папке где установлен питон папка Scripts, открываете консоль (cmd) переходите в эту папку (cd путь до папки scripts) и пишете `pip install pygame`

Comment: @Стас , спасибо, но я не     очень понял, куда писать ```pip install pygame```

Comment: @Антон переходите в папку где установлен питон, далее в папку scripts, запоминаете путь. Далее Win +R пишете в открывшемся окошке cmd, открывается консоль. В неё пишете `cd путь до папки, который вы запомнили` и в той же консоли пишете `pip install pygame`. Если вы при установке питона выбрали пункт *добавить питон в path*, то вам не нужно никуда переходить, просто напишите `pip install pygame` в консоль

Comment: @Стас ,спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том как вы устанавливаете модули.
Легко устанавливать разнообразные модули помогает команда pip, но чтобы она заработала, скорее всего вам нужно настроить переменные среды. Вот [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgCJwDjm_Cw) показана установка pyinstall и дана пошаговая инструкция, что делать если pip не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно переустановить Python, или модифицировать установку, поставив галочку на Add pip to PATH. A а если не работает команда pip, просто введите:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

Где: -m - это флаг о запуске модуля из папки Scripts.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

установите библиотеку pygame.
pip install pygame
в командной строке.
после:
import pygame
добавте строку:
pygame. init()

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).